# Testing the creation of files in Rails that are subsequently deleted in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to figure out how I can test a Rails controller's creation of a file when it's subsequently deleted.

I have a controller that creates a CSV file, sends it to the user, and then deletes it from the server. It looks something like this:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def download_file
     generate_file
     send_data File.read(filename)
     delete_file
  end

  private

  def generate_file
     # code that creates a file
  end

  def delete_file
     File.delete(filename)
  end
end
```

My test file:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe WelcomeController :type => :controller do
  describe 'GET #download_file' do
    it 'creates csv files' do
      get :download_file
      expect(File.file?(filename)).to be true # fails because file is deleted
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to test the fact that `download_file` creates a csv file, however I can't seem to figure out how to tell Rails that I want the `delete_file` method ignored when in my test environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current environment with `Rails.env`

```
def download_file
  generate_file
  send_data File.read(filename)
  delete_file unless Rails.env.test?
end
```

It's usually a bad design to have different behavior per environment. Consider instead testing the data sent by `send_data` (look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357563/how-to-test-send-data-in-rspec-or-what-should-i-be-testing-for-in-this-case) for an example)

Comment: Thank you - I think testing `send_data` instead makes more sense. I'll try that approach following the question you linked to.